Characterisation of convex absorbing sets $A$ such that $\{x \in X \mid \mu_{A}(x) < 1 \}=A$
So I came across this question which asks us to characterise the convex absorbing sets $A \subseteq X$ which satisfy $\{x\in X \mid \mu_{A}(x) < 1 \}=A$.
Here, $\mu_A$ denotes the Minkowski functional on the set $A$ defined as $\mu_A(x) = \inf \{\lambda > 0 : x \in \lambda A\}$ (taken to be $\infty$ if the set is empty)
I am studying functional analysis from Rudin and all I see are results related to balanced absorbing convex sets. I know for balanced absorbing convex sets, the semi-norm is precisely the Minkowski functional.
The relevant theorems are cited as follows:
Theorem 1.34:

Suppose $p$ is a semi-norm on a vector space $X$, then $B=\{x \mid p(x) < 1\}$ is a convex, balanced, absorbing set with $p=\mu_A$.

Theorem 1.35:

Suppose $A$ is a convex absorbing set in a vector space $X$.  Then

$\mu_A(x+y)\leq\mu_A(x) +\mu_A(y)$,
$\mu_A(tx) =t\mu_A(x)$ if $t\ge0$, and
$\mu_A$ is a semi-norm provided $A$ is balanced, and
if $B=\{x \mid \mu_A(x) < 1 \}$ and $C=\{x \mid \mu_A(x) \leq 1 \}$, then $B \subseteq A \subseteq C$ and $\mu_A = \mu_B = \mu_C$.


Theorem 1.36:

Suppose $\frak{B}$ is a convex balanced local base in a TVS $X$. Associate to every $V \in \frak{B}$, its minkowski functional $\mu_V$. Then

$V=\{ x \in X \mid \mu_V(x) < 1 \}$ for every $V \in \frak{B}$, and
the collection $\{ \mu_V \}$ forms a separating family of continuous semi-norms on $X$.


I can see that the question is closely related to the latter two theorems. But I am unable to figure out a "base" (just the topological base) or make sense of a "balanced" set in the current setting.

I am familiar with the notion of a Minkowski functional---I have never seen it made unique with "the".  Could you please edit your question to recall the definition?

I have tried to edit the question to make it a bit more readable (I only opened up the editor to properly capitalize Minkowski, but some of the formatting was a bit strange---I hope you don't mind, I've implemented some more standard Markdown).  As I re-read the question, it would also, perhaps, be helpful to give relevant definitions of "base" and "balanced" (both of these should be defined somewhere; I can guess about base (i.e. a topological base), and maybe people with more expertise know these already, but it can't hurt to add the definitions).

@XanderHenderson the Minkowski functional should be $\mu_A(x) = \inf {\lambda > 0 : x \in \lambda A}$, possibly $\infty$ if the set is empty.

@GeorgeCoote Ah. That would make sense in the context of the question. The author should edit that in...

What is the question?

@copper.hat Isn't that in the title ? I am looking for something like a necessary and sufficient condition on the set $A$

@Snowflake it would be better to make it obvious.
